# How to Change Radius of SKSpriteNode in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

I need to create a circle that starts in the middle of the screen with a tiny radius, which grows out gradually from the centre. Is there any way I can do this if the circle is an `SKSpriteNode`? Idea is for the radius to increase, without other qualities like stroke increasing.

So far:

```
func randomCircle(){
    let RandomCircleShape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 1)
    RandomCircleShape.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    RandomCircleShape.strokeColor = randomColor()
    RandomCircleShape.lineWidth = 2
    self.addChild(RandomCircleShape)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one way of achieving an expanding circle that maintains its line width. Add a radius argument to your function and have it return an `SKShapeNode`. Also, add properties for the node and the radius to your `GameScene` class:

```
var randomCircle: SKShapeNode?
var currentRadius: CGFloat = 1

func makeRandomCircle(radius: CGFloat) -> SKShapeNode {
    let RandomCircleShape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius)
    RandomCircleShape.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    RandomCircleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
    RandomCircleShape.lineWidth = 2
    return RandomCircleShape
}
```

Then create the expanding effect by changing the radius over time while adding and removing the nodes on the main thread:

```
var i = 0
while i < 300 {
    let delay = 0.001 * Double(i) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.currentRadius += 0.25
        self.randomCircle!.removeFromParent()
        self.randomCircle = self.makeRandomCircle(self.currentRadius)
        self.addChild(self.randomCircle!)
    }
    i++
}
```

This code can be placed where you want the effect to happen.

GIF of the result:

[image]